# Input width percentage not behaving correctly

Tags: css, html, input, width

I would like my input field to be 98% of the width of the container it is in. The problem is that when I set it to 98% width the input goes off the screen. Is there a special way to define a width of an input or something?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="large-12 columns centered">
     <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Start typing to search"  spellcheck="false" autofocus />
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
input {
    padding: 0.8rem 0.9rem;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
}
```

But for some reason, this is the result:
[image: Input Width]

Comment: Nevermind, there was an external CSS file that was causing the issue, it has been resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

Try providing [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for the input, so that width and height of the input considers padding as well.

```
input {
    padding: 0.8rem 0.9rem;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the final width of an element is calculated with `width + padding + border`, this is called [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Adding the following CSS should fix it:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use box-sizing should work:

```
input {
    width: percentage you want%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```